# Wordpress setup one database with two different website?

Tags: wordpress

Hello Friends I want to setup two website `first.com` and `second.in` that are different domain and server.

I want to a same data base in both site with the same content.

```
means we enter new posts in first.com then after that posts show in both sites.
```

i want to share every thing in both site like posts,page,comment,etc....

Comment: Note that this approach will reduce your ranking in search engines

Comment: make  db, user,pass same for both sites in wp-config.php . this may work

Comment: @pr1nc3 but url is not same in both site. wordpress store url in wp_options table.

Comment: Interesting reading - http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/tools-manage-multiple-wordpress-sites-one-location/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hiii renishkhunt just set that two line into your wp-config.php file second.in.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://second.in');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://second.in');
```

other then every thing is same in both site like the database connection and prefix etc..